# Cannot read property 'host' of undefined

Tags: android, iphone, uiwebview, cordova, android-webview

I have a problem of creating a webview in android/iphone and filling it with html.

the only thing that is working is:
Loading the embed code from external URL to the same url.

what can be the problem?

thnks,

Eliza

Comment: The question is not quite clear. Isn't the webview loading from external URL or assets folder?

Comment: What is the problem are you facing? Please provide more details

Comment: Hi thank you for your answer I found the problem:

I had this code line:
this.host = defaultUri.host;

this.host is empty string so the app crashes, but when I give a url for example 

this.host = www.example.com

everything seems to be ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So at the end my solution was very simple.

I had this source code:

```
  if ( !this.host ) {
    this.host = defaultUri.host;
    // port ?
    if ( !this.port ) {
        this.port = defaultUri.port;
        }
    }
```

just add: try & catch and everything will work!